# Secure session login to server on phonegap

Tags: ios, session, cordova

I have had a look around to try to get some info on how to create a secure login and session on a phone gap app for ios. I'm trying to talk to an online server via an api. Can anyone give some tips or some starting point?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want a secure login or secure interactions between your client and server?

If you want a secure login i would recommend you to transmit your username and password via. HTTPS to the server. On server-side you check it and if its ok you respond a session-token and a session cookie. For the rest of the interactions you only send your sessoin-cookie to identify yourself. When the user turns off the app, and starts it again you check your token expiraton date, if its still vaild you send your token to the server instead of username + password (HTTPS again) to get a new session-cookie.

With this way you dont have to transmit your user-data all the time and the user does not have to login every time he starts the app. You could also achieve this behavour if you store username and password on phone but thats very bad practice. If you want a totally secure connection between client and server (like for payments and stuff), you have to do it all with HTTPS.

Basically you use standard web-technologies. This way to handle this is called Token-Authentication.